# Java problems in query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
String data[]=new String[10];
String[] result;
Product p= new Product();
int serial=0;
try{
    String sql="select * from product";
    rslt=st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rslt.next()){
        data[1]=rslt.getString("p_code");
        data[2]=rslt.getString("catagory");
        data[3]=rslt.getString("p_name");
        data[4]=rslt.getString("description");
        data[5]=rslt.getString("measurement");
        //data[6]=Integer.toString(p.RemainProduct(data[1])); //Stock
        //data[7]=p.getSellPrice(data[1]); //sell price
        serial+=1;
        data[0]=Integer.toString(serial);
        DTB.addRow(data);
    }

}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("ERROR :"+ex);
}
```

the above code shows me all the product from database as desired here is the result [image]

but when i uncomment  `data[6]` and `data[7]` then it shows me only one product information from database.here is my result
[image]
My `RemainProduct(data[1])` and `getSellPrice(data[1])` method is working fine because it is giving the actual stock and sell price for the product.My problem is why i am getting only one result when i uncomment those two line.someone please fix this problem.

here is my getSellPrice method

```
   public String getSellPrice(String pCode){
    String[] data;
    String[] price= new String[2];
    data=productDB.getProductPrice(pCode);
    int i=0; 
    for(String s:data){
       price[i]=s;
       i +=1;
    }
    String sell=price[1];
    return sell;
}
```

and here is my remainproduct method

```
  public int RemainProduct(String pCode){
  if(oc.isOrdered(pCode)){
      int remain=Integer.parseInt(ProductTotalStock(pCode))-Integer.parseInt(prouductTotalSold(pCode))-getProductOrdered(pCode);
      return remain;
  }else{
      int remain=Integer.parseInt(ProductTotalStock(pCode))-Integer.parseInt(prouductTotalSold(pCode));
      return remain;
  }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you got some exception. Did you get the message you print in the `catch` block?

Comment: no i don't get any exception

Comment: What's happening in ``p.RemainProduct(data[1])``?

Comment: it just returns the remain product @qqilihq

Comment: Please, give the code.

Comment: May be the `addRow` fails for the rest two entries?

Comment: i tried system print but it gives me the same result. i also tried commenting the addrow() but not get the desired result @ShashankKadne

Comment: You must get an Exception. Either where you catch it or a runtimeException of one of the parsings of String to integer. What's the output to stdout, stderr or log?

Comment: it doesn't give anything.and if the problem is on parsing then how would it give a value.my problem is, i am not getting any row after the first row in database when i uncomment those two line.@jboi